# Как заставить MediaController работать корректно сразу?

Tags: android

Когда я начинаю проигрывание трека, MediaController показывается, однако ползунок не двигается, не отображается длина трека, вместо кнопки 'pause' стоит кнопка 'play'. Однако, если я передвигаю этот ползунок, все сразу начинает идеально работать: показывается длина, трек проигрывается с момента времени, на который был передвинут ползунок и кнопка 'play' сменяется на 'pause'.

Какой метод MediaController необходимо применить, чтобы:
1) Ползунок в момент времени начала проигрывания встал в самую начальную позицию и начал двигаться?
2) Была показана кнопка 'Pause'?
3) Отображалась длина трека?